# How To bind ListView values depends on combobox selected item?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, combobox

Hi all i want to bind my listbox depends on combobox selected item here is my code

```
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <ComboBox Name="cmbID" Width="150"  Margin="10" Height="30" SelectedItem="{Binding CmbSelected,Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="ID" ItemsSource="{Binding MyStudent,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Button Name="btnGetDetail"  Margin="10" Command="{Binding getDetails}" Content="Get Details" Height="30" Width="90"/>
            <TextBox Name="tbName1" Width="90" Height="30" Text="{Binding ElementName=cmbID,Path= SelectedItem.Sub}"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
```

In Above code i am binding my combobox to one observable collection and want to bind my ListView to selected item of combobox below is my code

```
 <ListView Name="myStudent" ItemsSource="{Binding CmbSelected,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="420"  Height="150">
            <ListView.View >
                <GridView x:Name="grdStudentDetails">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ElementName=cmbID,Path=SelectedItem.ID}" Width="30"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ElementName=cmbID,Path =SelectedItem.Name}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="RollNum" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ElementName=cmbID,Path=SelectedItem.RollNum}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Subject" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ElementName=cmbID,Path=SelectedItem.Sub}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="PhNumber" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ElementName=cmbID,Path=SelectedItem.PhNum}" Width="100"/>
                </GridView>


            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

I am not able to find where I am doing mistake even I bind my text box with same binding it is working fine. please refer textbox just below my combobox's XAML.

**my viewmodle.cs code is as follow**

```
private student cmbSelcted;

    public student CmbSelected
    {
        get { return cmbSelcted; }
        set { cmbSelcted = value; OnPropertyChanged("CmbSelected"); }
    }


    public ObservableCollection<student> MyStudent
    {
        get { return myStudent; }
        set { myStudent = value; OnPropertyChanged("MyStudent"); }
    }
```

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Comment: there is no error but also binding is now reflecting

Answer (score 0):

Can't see the ItemsSource of your ListView! Hope you've bind it to an collection. If not - try this approach.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedStudents, Mode=OneWay}">
            <ListView.View >
                <GridView x:Name="grdStudentDetails">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}" Width="30"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="RollNum" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RollNum}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Subject" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Sub}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="PhNumber" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PhNum}" Width="100"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

ViewModel

```
private Student _cmbSelected;
public Student CmbSelected
{
    get { return _cmbSelected; }
    set
    {
        _cmbSelected = value;
        if (_cmbSelected != null)
        {
            SelectedStudents = new List<Student>() { _cmbSelected };
        }
        else
        {
            SelectedStudents = new List<Student>();
        }
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

private List<Student> _selectedStudents;
public List<Student> SelectedStudents
{
    get { return _selectedStudents; }
    set
    {
        _selectedStudents = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Hope you see that it's important to have an ItemsSource on your ListView.

Comment: hello sir,
yeah i already bind itemsource to an collection but its still not reflecting in binding.i have edited my post plz have look .
there is one more thing if i applying same binding to text box its working but in listview its not reflecting somewhere i am missing something

Comment: Though I still can't see the ItemsSource-Binding of your ListView. Please edit it too.

Comment: Bind a list/collection to your `ListView` `ItemsSource` and everything works fine. Please also change the binding path on the ´DisplayMemberBinding´ as I did.

Comment: i tried but still nothing happen.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4fArMytRDVPREF3bDZBT0tudEk

plz have look on my application.plz look on right side combobox and below listview

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <ListView x:Name="usergrid" Margin="100,50,100,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=user1}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="UserId"       DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UserId,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="100" ></GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="First Name"   DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName,Mode=TwoWay}"  Width="150" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name"    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="150" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="City"         DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding City,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="150" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="State"        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding State,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="150" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Country"      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Country,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="150" />
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```