# Is there a way to bind the command to a ListView or ComboBox selection?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I am not able to find the way to bind the commands to my `listview` or `combobox` selection event or any mouse click event using `mvvm`.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
     <ComboBox Name="cmbID" Width="150"  Margin="10" Height="30" SelectedItem="{Binding CmbSelected,Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="ID" ItemsSource="{Binding MyStudent,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
     <Button Name="btnGetDetail"  Margin="10" Command="{Binding getDetails}" Content="Get Details" Height="30" Width="90"/>
     <TextBox Name="tbName1" Width="90" Height="30" Text="{Binding ElementName=cmbID,Path= SelectedItem.Sub}"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Where in `xaml` command property is not coming like in button we get.

Comment: Having a `Command` property on `ComboBox` wouldn't be very logical - what did you expect it do to? There are many ways to react to WPF events, for instance behaviors or triggers. If you could add more details about what exactly it is you want to do I think you would get more answers

Comment: hello sir
i am binding observable collection to my combo box and and also binding SelectedItem property to one property of my class.what i want to do is when i select any value from combobox lets say i selected ID(i choose displaymemberpath as a ID) on behalf of ID i want to bind other data in my listbox for that im not able to bind it properly 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40904574/how-to-bind-listview-values-depends-on-combobox-selected-item/40905325#40905325
pls look on this thread for more details

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVVM pattern, to execute a method when a item is selected in a `ListView` or `ComboBox`, all you have to do is put it in your `SelectedItem` setter. Using your example, in your viewmodel you must have a property like this:

```
private object _cmbSelected;
public object CmbSelected
{
     get
     {
         return this._cmbSelected;
     }
     set
     {
         this._cmbSelected= value;
         //Here you can put your method  
         NotifyPropertyChanged("CmbSelected");
     }
}
```

When a item is selected, the setter is called and there you can call any method you want. In this example, change `object` to the appropiate type.

Comment: can you plz share xaml code for that?
i already created this property
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40904574/how-to-bind-listview-values-depends-on-combobox-selected-item/40905325#40905325
plz reffer this post

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `EventTrigger`s and `InvoceCommandAction`s provided by the `System.Windows.Interactivity`.

```
<Window mlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">
...
    <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding CmbSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyStudent}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding YourCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ComboBox/>
...
</Window>
```

By the way, there is no point in setting the `ItemsSource` `Binding` to the `TwoWay` mode. As the name states, it is a **source** and will never update the bound property.